# Balanced brackets using Python

Tags: python, arrays, stack

I want to implement an algorithm, that can find errors in the usage of brackets in string

I read several examples, and came to idea of creating special class for brackets with function of matching opening and closing brackets

```
class Bracket:
    def __init__(self, bracket_type, position):
        self.bracket_type = bracket_type
        self.position = position

    def Match(self, c):
        if self.bracket_type == '[' and c == ']':
            return True
        if self.bracket_type == '{' and c == '}':
            return True
        if self.bracket_type == '(' and c == ')':
            return True
        return False
```

Next, I'm using stack, whether sting is balanced or not. I created a loop, going through every symbol, and if symbol is a bracket I want to assign it to my special class in order to match for closing one further.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = sys.stdin.read()

    opening_brackets_stack = []
    Balanced = True
    bracket = Bracket


    for i, symbol in enumerate(text):
        if symbol in ['(', '[', '{']:
            bracket.bracket_type = symbol
            opening_brackets_stack.append(symbol)

        elif bracket.Match(bracket.bracket_type, symbol) == True:
            opening_brackets_stack.pop(symbol)

        elif len(opening_brackets_stack) == 0:
            True
```

But, unfortunately that doesn't work.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bracket_type'
```

Why that is happening?
And what can you say about structure of algorithm - is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `bracket` to be an instance of the class `Bracket`, you'll need to instantiate it:

```
bracket = Bracket()
#     note these ^^
```

You're also going to get an error on `bracket.Match()` regarding passing too many arguments. You should call that method like so:

```
bracket.Match(symbol)
```

since the instance of `Bracket()` (`bracket`) is implicitly passed as `self`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to construct a stack of Bracket objects as opening symbols come in, and attempt to match the top of the stack to closing symbols as they appear. This approach is sound.

However, you have some confusion about how to declare an object in python. A new object is instantiated like this:

```
myObject = MyClass(constructor_arg_1, constructor_arg_2)
```

Specifically, your Bracket class has the following constructor:

```
new_bracket = Bracket(bracket_type, position)
```

Use that syntax to create a new bracket, then push it onto the stack:

```
bracket_stack.append(new_bracket)
```

That should clear up your problem, but I have some further advice if you care to read on:

- Looks like there's no reason for the Bracket objects to know their own positions; consider removing that from the constructor.
- Typical Python convention is to name your classes with Uppercase and their methods in lowercase. Consider renaming Bracket.Match to Bracket.match (or better yet, .isMatch, which makes it clear to the reader that it performs a check and returns a boolean value).

For more on objects in Python, you can read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm